# Understanding indexed families of sets

Tags: logic

So I am looking at this family of sets. It has an indexed set of $[0,1]$ where
every $x∈[0,1]=  \{y∈R |x_0≠0\ \text{AND} \ x_0≤y≤1 \}$

The question is asking which of the following six statements are true. But I am not interested in the answer, I just want to understand what exactly the indexed set means in this regard. Is the reason why $C_0 = Ø$, because that $x_0≠0$?

[image]

Comment: It just means you have a family of many sets, one for each number $x_0$ in the interval $[0,1]$. For example, using the given definition, we can see that $C_{0.5}$ is the interval $[0.5,1]$.

Comment: But why is C0 =Ø

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, it's because $x_0$ ≠ 0.

Comment: If $x_0=0$ then the expression $x_0\ne 0\land x_0\le y\le 1$ is always false, so the set is empty. See [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the starting statement

> every $x\in[0,1]=\{y\in R\;|\;x_{0}\neq 0\ \text{AND} \ x_{0}\leq y\leq 1 \}$

is questionable. Notice that $x\in[0,1]$ is $x\in\{y\in\mathbb{R}\;|\;0\leq y\leq 1 \}$ by definition. You can check out the rest, I'll skip to the quote:

We assume $x_{0}\in[0, 1]$. Hence,  $x_{0}\in\{y\in\mathbb{R}\;|\;0\leq y\leq 1 \}$. What if $x_{0}=0$, which has been allowed by the assumption?

$C_{0}=\{y\in\mathbb{R}\;|\;0\neq 0\wedge 0\leq y\leq 1 \}=\emptyset$ by the conjunct $0\neq0$.

The rest of the sets of the family is indexed by the values of $x_{0}$ but $0$ being left out, that is, in the open interval $]0, 1]$ (alternative notation is $(0, 1]$).